# Probability of lottery jackpot with or without bonus ball

Tags: statistics

I understand that for a lottery where you choose 6 numbers in a draw from 49 balls the probability is

$$\frac{1}{{n\choose k}}=\frac{1}{{49\choose 6}}.$$

I am not sure if the following calculation is correct:

We introduce a bonus ball with a bigger jackpot, whereby you select a number that is independent from the above draw, and is drawn independent from the above draw from a set of 49 balls. Then the probability of selecting 6 balls and the bonus correctly.

$$\frac{1}{{49\choose 6}} * \frac{1}{49}$$

Now, the probability of winning either with or without the bonus ball. That is to choose 6 numbers correctly OR choose 6 numbers AND the bonus ball correctly

$$ \frac{1}{{49\choose 6}}+\frac{1}{{49\choose 6}} * \frac{1}{49}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Its $\binom{49}{6}$, not $\binom{6}{49}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not correct.  Note that the event of choosing $6$ regular balls and bonus ball correctly is a subset of the event of choosing $6$ regular balls correctly.  Thus the probability of winning with or without the bonus ball is just $\frac{1}{49\choose 6}$.

If you want to break it out by cases: $6$ correct without bonus or $6$ correct with bonus, you can rewrite as
$$\frac{1}{{49\choose 6}}\cdot \frac{48}{49}+\frac{1}{{49\choose 6}}\cdot \frac{1}{49}$$ which conditions on whether you don't or do get the bonus ball (along with the $6$ regular balls).